# Transfer function just from data?

Tags: transfer-function, matlab

Is Matlab able to formulate a second order transfer function from just a dataset of 2 inputs and their 2 outputs or I still need to conduct a step response on my MIMO model to calculate the TF parameters?

Comment: Please detail your question. (add a schematic of the system, explain briefly the context, name the variables and functions)

Comment: It was for theoretical knowledge @MaximGi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a identification toolbox in Matlab that can give you TF based on input and output data.
System identification toolbox.

Comment: I know this tool and i used it sometimes but how i can be sure it's doing a good fit for the TF model?

Comment: Toolbox provides the possibility to use half of data set for identification and second half for verification, then you can see a percentage of matching ( choose the highest one). Different methods of identification will give you different results, but it is hard to be 100% sure. When you have 90%+, you have a great identification.